# If $I$ and $J$ are two ideals of a Lie algebra L then $(I+J)^{2n}\subset I^{n}+J^{n}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, lie-algebras, ideals, binomial-theorem

For an ideal $I$ of a Lie algebra $L$ we define $I^{0}=I$ and $I^{k}=[I,I^{k-1}]$ for $k\geq1.$ I want to prove the following

**Proposition:** If $I$ and $J$ are two ideals of L then $(I+J)^{2n}\subset I^{n}+J^{n}.$

I know this theorem in case of commutative associative rings, but it uses the binomial formula $(x+y)^{k}=\sum\begin{pmatrix}k\\i\end{pmatrix}x^{k-i}y^{i}.$ Then one argues that if $x\in I,$ $y\in J$ and $k=2n,$ then always either $i\geq n$ or $k-i\geq n$ and therefore each elements of the righthand side is either in $I^{n}$ or in $J^{n}.$

**Question:** is there any generalisation of the binomial formula to the case of Lie algebras or at least noncommutative associative rings?

If no then how one proves the first proposition? I was also trying induction but I didn't came up with anything interesting. I will be thankful for any reference or a hint.

Comment: For Lie algebras, $IJ=JI$ is commutative for ideals, because $xy=-yx$ for all $x,y$ in the Lie algebra.

Comment: @DietrichBurde but to use the binomial formula for ideals we also need associativity for ideals and I don't think this is true.

Answer (score 1):

The claim is proved in Proposition $6$ on page $25$ in Jacobson's book on Lie algebras. Writing $IJ$ for $[I,J]$ in the Lie algebra case for ideals, we have for Lie algebra ideals $I,J$
\begin{align*}
IJ & =JI, \\
(IJ)K & \subseteq (IK)J+(JK)I
\end{align*}
by the skewsymmetry and the Jacobi identity. It is straightforwward to show that $(I+J)^m\subseteq I^{[m/2]}+J^{[m/2]}$, see Jacobson.